# Event of clicking on buttons in the ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, button

Studying the templates, I was interested in how I can get the events of clicking on this or that template button. Using a simple template as an example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 01" />
            <Button Content="Button 01" />
            <Button Content="Button 02" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControlName" Template="{StaticResource ControlTemplateKey}" />
```

To determine the click on one or another element (in this case, the button), I iterate over the contents of the tree:

```
ContentControlName.PreviewMouseDown += (s, e) =>
{
    DependencyObject i = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(s as Visual, Mouse.GetPosition(s as IInputElement)).VisualHit;

    while (i != null)
    {
        if (i is Button)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((i as Button).Content);
            break;
        }

        i = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(i);
    }
};
```

However, I think that there is an easier way specifically for this than my iteration over the tree. How can I more easily identify the pressed button in the template? Thanks

Comment: What will happens on button click? You don't really need *hit tests* for buttons. They already have support for command, which you bind to `ICommand` properties.

Comment: Thank. When you press this or that button, a certain code occurs. Sinatr, you mean something like this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/wpf-icommand-in-mvvm/ ?

Comment: What are you using such a template for?
Let's say how you define Text = "TextBlock 01" values ​​for a ContentControl instance.
Or are they all the same?
Typically, the data provider for an element is the DataContext, and data is retrieved from it through bindings. For example Text = "{Binding Text01}".
Therefore, the most correct would be to use the commands, as @Sinatr wrote.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct remark, I did not indicate in the question that the template is used repeatedly with different properties of elements, which are set through Binding. I am focused on events. And I got a good answer from EldHasp - access via Command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a solution outside of the MVVM pattern, you can still use command bubbling.
For this, the RoutedCommand class is used.

```
<Window x:Class="ClickInTemplate.ClickWind"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ClickInTemplate"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ClickWind" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ControlTemplateKey" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="TextBlock 01" />
            
                <!--Any data can be passed in the parameter.
                In this example, I am passing in the parent ContentControl.-->
                <Button Content="Button 01" Command="Find"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}}"/>

                <!--In this example, I am passing just text.-->
                <Button Content="Button 02" Command="Cut"
                        CommandParameter="The button was pressed &quot;Button 02&quot;"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentControlName" Template="{StaticResource ControlTemplateKey}">
            <ContentControl.CommandBindings>
                <CommandBinding Command="Find" Executed="Find_Executed"/>
                <CommandBinding Command="Cut" Executed="Cut_Executed"/>
            </ContentControl.CommandBindings>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ClickInTemplate
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для ClickWind.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ClickWind : Window
    {
        public ClickWind()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Find_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Parameter is ContentControl control)
            {
                // The variable "control" contains the ContentControl that was clicked.
                MessageBox.Show("Command \"Find\" in " + control.Name);
            }
        }

        private void Cut_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Parameter is string text)
            {
                // The variable "control" contains the ContentControl that was clicked.
                MessageBox.Show("Command \"Cut\" with Text=\"" + text + "\"");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used the commands already implemented in Net, but you can create your own static instances if you want.

Comment: This is a very important knowledge for me and I think for many beginners. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you speak Russian, see this link: https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2384523.html

Answer (score 1):

You usually register event handlers to handle events.
One parameter of the handler is the sender object. This sender is in your case the `Button` instance that raised this event.

Aside from using an `EventTrigger`, there are basically four ways to listen to an UI event (routed event):

E.g. inside a `UIElement` e.g. a `Window`:

```
AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnButtonClicked));
```

or

```
// Requires a named element using x:Name e.g. <Button x:Name="Button1" />
this.Button1.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnButtonClicked));
this.Button2.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnButtonClicked));
```

or

```
this.Button1.Click += OnButtonClicked;
this.Button2.Click += OnButtonClicked;
```

In XAML you can attach a handler either directly to the source element or to any parent `UIElement` of the source element:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" 
                Click="OnButtonClicked" />
<Button x:Name="Button2" 
                Click="OnButtonClicked" />
```

or

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentControlName" 
                Button.Click="OnButtonClicked" />
```

Finally handle the event. Each way to listen to an event uses the same event handler:

```
private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // 'sender' parameter references the Button instance,
  // that was actually clicked (Button1 or Button2)
  var clickedButton = sender as Button;
}
```

Alternatively, you can attach a dedicated event handler to each `Button` e.g., `OnButton1Clicked` and `OnButton2Clicked`.

Comment: Thank. Event handlers work fine when no control is set in resources. However, in my case, the common template is specified in the resource. And if I ask for any property of this or that button (for example, button.Content), then I get the error "the link does not point to an object."

Comment: This is not normal, you _must'_ do something wrong.. It doesn't matter if the `Button` is defined as a resource or inside a template. You can always set its properties e.g. `<Button Click="OnClick" />` etc. I don't know what you are doing. But this will _always_ work any time. I wouldn't have posted this if it won't work.

Comment: Yes, it is, and in order to access through one of the template instances, I must act as follows: ```Button button = ContentControlName.Template.FindName("Button1", ContentControlName) as Button;
button.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnButtonClicked));```

Comment: You don't _need_ the button instance! To lookup the event source in the template is not necessary. Those are _routed events_. They travel up (bubbling)  and down (tunneling) the visual tree. While traveling they can be handled by every `UIElement` on the route. You just register the handler like: `this.AddHandler(Button:ClickEvent, ...)`. The instance or event source itself doesn't matter in order to register a routed event. You can simply add `AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnButtonClicked));` to your constructor of e.g. `MainWindow`. It will work.

Comment: You can attach the handler in XAML too: `<Button Click="OnButtonClicked" />`. This is the recommended solution.